# где найти учебник или руководство по изучению Prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

нигде в интернете не могу найти самоучитель или руководство по изучению prettytable. Желательно подробно и в русской версии. Как делать в таблице расчеты, регулировать ширину строк, перенос строк, делать ссылки и прочее. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В идеале неплохо бы прочитать [официальную документацию](https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) *PrettyTable*.
2. Так же вот есть неплохой [туториал](https://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/).
3. Туториал с *[GitHub](https://github.com/vishvananda/prettytable)*.
4. Небольшой [видеоролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgR71d4PQjA) с кратким туториалом.

Comment: туториал и официальная документация недостаточны, ну ни как!?